Add jsPDF to Appsmith not working and show Script error
I want to create a resume maker with appsmith and jsPDF.
when use from react without appsmith its working but when use in appsmith show this error:
Script error.  console.ts:53 
error   @   console.ts:53
(anonymous) @   evaluation.worker.ts:79

I don't know what is happened in my system.
I ask from GPT and Phind.com but their solution not working.
